# MySQL Query Questions (number of queries sent to the server.)?

Tags: php, mysql

The website I am currently developing is handled by a variety of classes that I have developed to ensure the best of my sites needs to run in tip-top shape.

The only thing I can think of right now is, how many questions(queries) should a user sending per page load?

This page does include the following:
Announcement - 5PER PAGE
USER LOGIN/VERIFICATION - EACH PAGE
VIDEO BLOG - CHECKS IF IT'S ENABLED OR OFF

8 queries on average are sent at a maximum of 3KB's per page. Should I be worried or encouraged to keep continuing? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know a site (a webshop) that performs quite well while executing a minimum of 400 queries per page and having over 2000 orders a day (let alone the page views).

Although I admit that is running on quite a heavy server and still could use some optimization.

But no, 8 queries is fine, and you could do with some more if you need to.

Comment: What would be ideally the critical point that would cause an overload? I heard 20,000 ~ 30,000 queries.

Comment: @tjm that's very hardware-, configuration-, app-, and *especially* data-dependent. You could try asking around on a sister site for specific db-tuning pointers (indexing, etc), but a lot of times it comes down to testing and finesse in tuning the db and application to best utilize the resources at hand.

Answer (score 1):

It's not about `how many questions`, it's about `smart questions`. You could select all records in table A and then use this result to get a matching result from table B, you could also use a single query using a JOIN and get the answer you're looking for.

The query count is not that important, it's all about how these queries help you to get the right anwser and how the queries are executed by the database server.  Use [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html) to see how a query is executed and see if something could be optimized.

Comment: as this commenter points out Query count is not as important as query optimization. But back on topic, 8 queries is quite ok